# Millennium Falcon escapes Vader's TIE by jettisoning water

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, millennium-falcon

I'm looking for a Star Wars comic book, which I read as a kid maybe in the mid-80's.

I only remember the climax, which was Millennium Falcon being chased by Vader in a TIE fighter. The heroes were pretty much done for, until they jettisoned Falcon's water supply. Water turned to ice, Vader damaged his TIE to ice blocks and was left spinning in space (similar to a New Hope), and the Millennium Falcon escapes.

I don't recall who was in the Falcon at that point, but I have feeling that at least Han, Chewie and Luke.

Sometimes I feel like I've been imagining whole story all this time, would be nice to get confirmation :)

Comment: I can't remember the issue, and my copy is long gone, but I can at least reassure you that you weren't imagining it.  It was definitely in one of Marvel's Star Wars comics (although the title may have changed to Return of the Jedi by that point).

Comment: Thanks for comments, glad to know it is real :) That comics series might very well be it, I'll check them more closely soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering this myself, with Jon B:s excellent lead I was able to track down the comic book. Issue in question was indeed one of Marvel's Star Wars series, No. 52 "To Take The Tarkin", October 1981.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_52:_To_Take_The_Tarkin :

> The Rebels Luke Skywalker, Leia Organa, and Chewbacca along with the droids C-3PO and R2-D2 have infiltrated the Imperial superweapon Tarkin with the intention of sabotaging it. While they are carrying out their plan, Darth Vader is arranging a confrontation with Luke, but a group of Imperial officers led by General Biel, are planning to destroy the Sith Lord. The officers' plan fails, but Vader decides to focus on capturing the Rebels and deal with the insurgents later. Having hampered the firing mechanism of the Tarkin, the Rebels escape the station but are attacked by a group of TIE fighters, including one piloted by Vader. Fortunately for the Rebels, Lando Calrissian had stowed aboard the Millennium Falcon and he pilots the freighter to the aid of the others. With Vader's fighter disabled, Biel attempts to fire the Tarkin's superlaser at the Rebels, hoping Vader would be caught in the blast. But the superweapon self-destructs at the time it fires, killing all on board.

Here's the scene described in OP, pretty much same except that Vader didn't end up spinning in space but was presumed destroyed (and crew of Falcon was different).

[image]

Comment: Although the water (how much water _does_ a Corellian Freight that is mostly empty carry??) would disperse into a fine mist of ice crystal not into a chunky gravel pit... (This trick also used in David Brin's ["Startide Rising"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startide_Rising), 1983)